# Unable to set edit permission to record creator only

Tags: permissions

So I have a custom object `Campaign__c` and a custom profile FullRead, this profile has Read, Create and Edit permission on `Campaign__c`, when it's set like that, all FullRead users can edit campaigns, even if they aren't the creator of the campaign. When I change the permission to Read and Create only, none of the users can edit campaign, not even the ones they created.
The OWD for this object is Controlled By Parent because it depends on the custom object `Brand__c`, which is Public Read Only.

How can I make `Campaign__c` editable only for the creator of the campaign? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root or your issue appears to be related to Campaign__c being controlled by parent. Brand__c is Read Only and the campaign owner is likely *not* the owner of the Brand__c parent record. As such, they don't have permission to edit the record they're creating since the parent record is read-only for them.

You can't give them sharing permission to edit the child record they've created if it's controlled by parent. Apparently this is a M-D detail relationship? If this is a look-up relationship, I'd recommend you remove the controlled by parent on this object and just make it public read only. Then, make it only editable to your Marketing Profile Users, members of a sharing group, or conditionally share it to the user who created it.

Comment: Your answer was right, the problem was caused by the M-D relationship. I tried to solve it sharing the `Brand__c` object to the `Campaign__c` owner but now it has access to all the campaigns under that brand. Sadly I'm not authorized to change the relationship type to a simple lookup. 
I will have to use visualforce to replace the standard functionallity and check if the user is the creator of the record to grant him access.
Thank you!

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the M-D and controlled by parent, you can't simply share the precise record by using either conditional sharing or apex managed sharing.